# Virtual desktop or virtual monitor

Tags: windows-7, windows, desktop

Does anyone know if there is a way that you can setup a virtual desktop or monitor using VNC? I have 2 windows 7 machines and would like to be able to connect them but in different user accounts so that I can work in one account while the other person works on the same machine in there account or virtual environment. Anyone know if that's possible with VNC or otherwise?

Answer (score 1):

By default, Windows 7 does not support concurrent users, whether on separate monitors or not, locally or remote. This is a licensing issue, rather than a techincal one. See this [TechNet article](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7itproinstall/thread/41e9e500-714a-443b-bff2-55f0d500d3d1/) for details.

However...

If you were to look closely at that article, perhaps near the bottom, you might find a couple of posts with additional information. These posts suggest that there are ways this can be done. Why those posts remain on a MS-run site is an open question.

I haven't tested these methods, nor do I intend to.